# Drupal create a page that outputs JSON

Tags: json, drupal

I would like to ask can one create a page that outputs JSON data as a response to Jquery Ajax request?

In a non-drupal way, I would just create a php file, for example mypage.php and then I would use http://example.com/mypage.php?foo=bar as the URL for my AJAX request. This page will then output JSON data using json_encode().

How can I do it the Drupal way?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

The [JSON server module](http://drupal.org/project/json_server) gives you JSON output of nodes.

If you want more custom JSON, you can use [hook_menu()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/hook_menu/6) to create a new menu callback (basically a URL path pointed to a function) and then use:

- [drupal_json()](http://api.drupal.org/api/function/drupal_json/6) - Drupal6
- [drupal_json_output()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_json_output/7) - Drupal7

within that callback to send the output as JSON rather than the default HTML.

Answer (score 38):

A working example of scott reynen's hint: in drupal 7,
in a module called mymodule, write

```
function mymodule_menu() {
    $items['fancystuff/json'] = array(
        'access callback'   => true, // available to all
        'page callback'     => 'mymodule_fancystuff_object', // defined below
        'delivery callback' => 'drupal_json_output' 
    );
    return $items;
}



function mymodule_fancystuff_object() {
    return array('test'=>true,'dummy'=>array(0,1));
}
```

clear your caches, goto http://example.com/fancystuff/json and behold

Comment: you can even `return views_get_view_result('fancystuff')` .. right back to json .. wow

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the `delivery callback` menu argument… I just set it up to deliver a binary file with the correct content header by following the example of the `drupal_json_output` function and creating my own callback. Pretty nifty…

Comment: there is a downside to using drupal_json_output as a delivery method. if it cant deliver content, for example because you have no rights to view them,  it will return a plain integer refering to some drupal constant describing the problem, like "3". The HTTP headers will say 200 OK.

Comment: .. which happened to me again today. 2 is file not found, 3 is access denied in d7

Comment: Just a quick note to point out that using `drupal_json_output` as a delivery callback for the menu item is slightly risky because errors like MENU_NOT_FOUND or MENU_ACCESS_DENIED would not be handled properly. A safer approach is to omit the `delivery_callback` argument and call `drupal_json_output()` from the menu callback, like in the following snippet: `return drupal_json_output(array("test" => true));`